# Create dummies for categorical data

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to build a Binary classifier, most of my variables are categorical. Hence I want to process categorical data into dummy vars. 
I have the following dataset:

```
ruri                object
ruri_user           object
ruri_domain         object
from_user           object
from_domain         object
from_tag            object
to_user             object
contact_user        object
callid              object
content_type        object
user_agent          object
source_ip           object
source_port          int64
destination_port     int64
contact_ip          object
contact_port         int64
toll_fraud           int64
```

I will pick only few features 10 out of 16:

```
def select_features(self, data):
        """Selects the features that we'll use in the model. Drops unused features"""
        features = ['ruri', 
                    'ruri_user', 
                    'ruri_domain', 
                    'from_user', 
                    'from_domain', 
                    'from_tag', 
                    'to_user',
                    'contact_user', 
                    'callid', 
                    'content_type', 
                    'user_agent', 
                    'source_ip', 
                    'source_port',
                    'destination_port', 
                    'contact_ip', 
                    'contact_port']
        dropped_features = ['ruri', 'ruri_domain', 'callid', 'from_tag', 'content_type', 'from_user']
        target = ['toll_fraud']
        X = data[features].drop(dropped_features, axis=1)
        y = data[target]
        return X, y
```

I split my dataset into training and test data. Initially both subsets have the same number of features, and after converting my features to categorical my number of variables change, hence is impossible to process model.

Before create_dummies:

```
1665 10
555 10
```

After create_dummies:

```
1665 1564
555 765
```

Here I create the dummies:

```
def create_dummies(self, data, cat_vars, cat_types):
        """Processes categorical data into dummy vars."""

        cat_data = data[cat_vars].values
        for i in range(len(cat_vars)):
            bins = LabelBinarizer().fit_transform(cat_data[:, 0].astype(cat_types[i]))
            cat_data = np.delete(cat_data, 0, axis=1)
            cat_data = np.column_stack((cat_data, bins))
        return cat_data


def preproc(self):
        """Executes the full preprocessing pipeline."""

        # Import Data & Split.
        X_train_, y_train, X_valid_, y_valid = self.import_and_split_data()
        # Fill NAs.
        X_train, X_valid = self.fix_na(X_train_), self.fix_na(X_valid_)
        # Preproc Categorical Vars
        cat_vars = ['ruri_user',
                    'from_domain',
                    'to_user',
                    'contact_user',
                    'user_agent',
                    'source_ip',
                    'contact_ip']

        cat_types = ['str', 'str', 'str', 'str', 'str', 'str', 'str']
        print 'Before create_dummies'
        print X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1]
        print X_valid.shape[0], X_valid.shape[1]

        X_train_cat, X_valid_cat = self.create_dummies(X_train, cat_vars, cat_types), self.create_dummies(X_valid,
                                                                                                          cat_vars,
                                                                                                          cat_types)

        print 'After create_dummies'
        print X_train_cat.shape[0], X_train_cat.shape[1]
        print X_valid_cat.shape[0], X_valid_cat.shape[1]

        X_train, X_valid = X_train_cat, X_valid_cat
        print 'After assignment'
        print X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1]
        print X_valid.shape[0], X_valid.shape[1]

        return X_train.astype('float32'), y_train.values, X_valid.astype('float32'), y_valid.values
```

Complete code [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/328e53cba8c1024e579aca18d22ab0b5)

Dataset [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1eb36b1c319062b185c092589c76a94a)

Original Code from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/mrklees/applying-keras-scikit-learn-to-titanic)

Comment: Create the dummies before to split in training and test data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you split your dataframe into train and test set some categories goes in train set and not in test set, that why you are getting different 
shapes for your train and test set!

As suggested in the comment you need to do all preprocessing before splitting into train and test sets.
Don't need to do preprocessing of train and test separately.

You will get all possibles categories encoded and then you can split

Comment: I did that, now it works, new issue I have is when submitting data to predict as when I create the submissions my features with the dummies are not the same as original train data. Example: I trained data with IP 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.2, etc. In new data request for prediction this column is not included and I end up having the same original issue I reported. Any ideas?

Comment: The new data need to be transform with the same encoder you user for train and test

Comment: In a production system where I train and test data, then I saved model and weights (Keras). How can I use the same encoder?

Comment: Okeyn you can save the encoder object, (Lable binarizer ) for your case, and call his transform method with the new data. once the new data is transformed you can predict using keras.