# Predict with categorical features

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, keras

I'm building a binary classification model with Keras.
[Dataset](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1eb36b1c319062b185c092589c76a94a) contains many categorical features (IP address, destination number, destination address, User Agent, etc.)

I'm unable to submit predictions as features are categorical and the number of columns of training and test data is different for predictions.

```
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/Development/Python/gl-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 1006, in predict
    return self.model.predict(x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/Development/Python/gl-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1772, in predict
    check_batch_axis=False)
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/Development/Python/gl-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 153, in _standardize_input_data
    str(array.shape))
ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_1_input to have shape (None, 2134) but got array with shape (34, 102)
```

I'm able to split data and train model.

```
ruri                object
ruri_user           object
ruri_domain         object
from_user           object
from_domain         object
from_tag            object
to_user             object
contact_user        object
callid              object
content_type        object
user_agent          object
source_ip           object
source_port          int64
destination_port     int64
contact_ip          object
contact_port         int64
toll_fraud           int64
```

This is my logic:

- Import data from CSV
- Drop unneeded columns
- Generate dummy columns (`encode_one_hot`)
- Split dataset into training and test data.
- Train model
- Evaluate it
- Submit predictions <-- **Fails**

This is my [code](https://gist.github.com/spicyramen/0080f4599cdc48deed256ce03a195fe8)

Training and test sizes

```
Samples Columns
1665 2134
555  2134
```

Functions:

```
def preproc_test(self):
        """Pre-process testing data."""

        #Import data
        test = self.import_data(self.test_fn, drop=True)
        # Extract labels.
        labels = test.user_agent.values
        # Fix NA values.
        test = self.fix_na(test)

        # Feature Engineering
        #test = self.engineer_features(test)

        # Create dummy variables.
        test = encode_one_hot(test, 'ruri_user')
        test = encode_one_hot(test, 'from_user')
        test = encode_one_hot(test, 'from_domain')
        test = encode_one_hot(test, 'to_user')
        test = encode_one_hot(test, 'contact_user')
        test = encode_one_hot(test, 'user_agent')
        test = encode_one_hot(test, 'source_ip')
        test = encode_one_hot(test, 'contact_ip')
        return labels, test


def prepare_submission(self, name):
        labels, test_data = self.preproc_test()
        predictions = self.model.predict(test_data)
        subm = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([labels, np.around(predictions[:, 1])]).astype('int32'),
                            columns=['user_agent', 'toll_fraud'])
        subm.to_csv('%s.csv' % name, index=False)
        return subm
```

Original [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48881881/create-dummies-for-categorical-data)

Not sure if I should resize to my predictions to the same number of original features/columns, if so what is the best way?

Comment: print the shape of train and test data.

Comment: Is in one of the comments above: Training and test sizes:

Samples Columns
1665 2134
555  2134